# Running batch file from command prompt getting error

Tags: java, batch-file

Hi I have a batch file which basically updates some table in the database by running the job.

Here is a batch file code:

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\jsoup-1.7.2.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\xstream-1.1.3.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-transport-http-1.6.1.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\httpclient-4.1.2.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\httpcore-4.1.2.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\gson-1.6.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\lucene-core-3.3.0.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-adb-1.6.1.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\axiom-api-1.2.12.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-kernel-1.6.1.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\axiom-impl-1.2.12.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\neethi-3.0.1.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\freemarker.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\smtp.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-transport-local-1.6.1.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-transport-http-1.6.1.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\mailapi.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\web\WEB-INF\classes;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\spring-asm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\aopalliance-1.0.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\spring-expression-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\transactions-jdbc-3.8.0.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\transactions-osgi-3.8.0.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-annotations-3.2.0.ga.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\transactions-hibernate3-3.8.0.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\gdata-core-1.0.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\xstream-1.1.3.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\commons-lang-2.3.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\xmlunit-1.5.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-transport-http-1.6.1.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\mailapi.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\web\WEB-INF\classes;

java -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m com.myProject.batch.PropertyRatesUpdaterBatchJob
```

I am trying to run the batch file from command prompt but I am getting error like

```
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\tools>C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\web\WEB-INF\classes;
'C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\web\WEB-INF\classes' is not recognized as an internal    or     external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

and the second error at the end I am getting as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/myProject/batch    /PropertyRatesUpdaterBatchJob
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:    com.myProject.batch.PropertyRatesUpdaterBatchJob
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
```

and I am not able to run the batch file. 
Anybody can help me to how to run the same and what this error mean.

Hi here is my new batch file:

```
    set CLASSPATH=C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\jsoup-1.7.2.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\xstream-1.1.3.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-transport-http-1.6.1.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\httpclient-4.1.2.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\httpcore-4.1.2.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\gson-1.6.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\lucene-core-3.3.0.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-adb-1.6.1.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\axiom-api-1.2.12.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-kernel-1.6.1.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\axiom-impl-1.2.12.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\neethi-3.0.1.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\freemarker.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\smtp.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-transport-local-1.6.1.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-transport-http-1.6.1.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\mailapi.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\WEB-INF\classes;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\spring-asm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\spring-expression-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\transactions-jdbc-3.8.0.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\transactions-osgi-3.8.0.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-annotations-3.2.0.ga.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\transactions-hibernate3-3.8.0.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\gdata-core-1.0.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\xstream-1.1.3.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\commons-lang-2.3.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\xmlunit-1.5.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-transport-http-1.6.1.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\mailapi.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\zaranga\build\zaranga\WEB-INF\classes

java -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m com.zaranga.batch.PropertyRatesUpdaterBatchJob
```

Now I am getting a new error log4j as 
Error is :

```
No org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder found in ClassPath, trying with log4j...
```

Any help will be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Can you show us the batchfile code? I suspect some ClassPath issue.

Comment: "C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\web\WEB-INF\classes;" is a Folder, you cannot execute that. There must be something missing in the batchfile.

Comment: Please check i have added the batch file content

Comment: "C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\web\WEB-INF\classes;" is twice in there and try "C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\web\WEB-INF\classes\\*;"

Comment: Everything before the `java` command must be written in 1 line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume with

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar;
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\jsoup-1.7.2.jar;
```

You wanted to also add `jsoup-1.7.2.jar;` to the `CLASSPATH` variable, but you can't just extend a command over multiple lines like that.

If you want to write this on multiple lines, each line (except for the last one of course) must *end* with the so called "line continuation character" which tells Windows that the command (in your case the `SET`) isn't finished yet, even though the line is. This character is `^` in Windows (comparable to the `\` in Linux/Unix shell scripts)

So what you need is:

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar; ^
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\jsoup-1.7.2.jar; ^
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\xstream-1.1.3.jar; ^
.... ^
.... ^
C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\web\WEB-INF\classes;

java -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m com.myProject.batch.PropertyRatesUpdaterBatchJob
```

<sup>(btw: you have `C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\web\WEB-INF\classes` twice in your list)</sup>

You must make sure that there is **no** whitespace whatsoever after the `^` otherwise this will not work.

Btw: you shouldn't be using the `CLASSPATH` variable anymore. It's better to explicitly define a classpath using the `-cp` (or `-classpath` parameter for the `java` command).

In recent (up-to-date) versions of Java for Windows you don't need to specify each element in the classpath variable.

Quote from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

> *As a special convenience, a class path element that contains a base name of * is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR*

So you can get rid of all the lines and just use:

```
java -cp C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\build\myProject\WEB-INF\lib\*;C:\ProjectWorkSpace\myProject\web\WEB-INF\classes  com.myProject.batch.PropertyRatesUpdaterBatchJob
```

Comment: +1 Nice feature, using `*` in class-path. It’s so easy to miss new features of newer Java versions…